# how to make my angular route work properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am building an app with ionic, I have a route in which I want to navigate to but it keeps redirecting me to the home route

here is the code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {  
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
    },
    {  
        path: 'home/:name/:id',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
    },
]; 
 
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I want to navigate to the `'home/:name/:id'` route by entering `http://localhost:8100/home/david/1` but it keeps redirecting me to the `http://localhost:8100/home` route, please what am I doing that is wrong

Comment: flip the   path: 'home/:name/:id', first and then home . issue should be fixed

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Try as I have suggested, another routing module

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional routing module `HomeRoutingModule` and add that to `HomePageModule`. Configure there such as:

```
{  
    path: ':name/:id',
    component: SomeComponent // <-- whatever you need
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the request to the server is only one, and the routes is for SPA ionic/angular. The server don't know the path after the host name.

For solve the problem you have 2 ways:

**Alter the router Strategy:**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**OR Setting the config file in the server (web.config, htaccess, etc...) - Only works when publish.**